# How can I pass dynamic data to DOM with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In my context, I got dynamic text brought by database (JS file).

But I don't know how to display that data to my HTML dynamicly.

The main ID is when I load the page, It automaticly display data (if there is data) on the "nom" field.

I am new to Vue.js so I'll need your help there, thanks.

Here is my js file :

```
var ip_adresse = new Vue({
  el: "#adresse_ip",
  data: {
    adresse: [],
  },
  created() {
    this.charger_adresse();
  },
  methods: {
    charger_adresse() { // Méthode

        var self = this;

        $.get(SITE_URL + '/modules/informations_pratiques/infos_mairie/load_adresse/' + APP_ID, function(reponse) {

            console.log(reponse);
            self.adresse.nom = reponse[0]['adresse'];
            console.log(self);


        });
    },
}
```

And here is my HTML :

```
 <article id="adresse_ip">
        <form action="">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="stay-strong">Renseignez l'adresse de la Mairie</p>
                <input name="nom" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="row submit">
                <button class="publish">Enregistrer les informations</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding your `input` element with the *data* object, like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#adresse_ip',
  data: {
    address: ''
  },
  created() {
    this.charger_adresse();
  },
  methods: {
    charger_adresse() {
        //fetch your data via AJAX and set it to the object
        this.address = 'foobar'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<article id="adresse_ip">
  <form action="">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="stay-strong">Renseignez l'adresse de la Mairie</p>
      <input name="nom" type="text" v-model="address" :val="address">
    </div>

    <div class="row submit">
      <button class="publish">Enregistrer les informations</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</article>
```

[Read more about form input bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)